# Sencha too slow

Tags: extjs

I introduced Sencha grid in one of my JSPs. Locally sencha is quite fast but on an external server it is too slow.
I followed deploy instructions here

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started

using ext-debug.js and my app.js.
Then, in my JSP, I imported app-all.js (670KB) and ext.js

[image: Chrome Network tab]

Where am I wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

app-all.js is 670KB, which is a **very big** file. You should refactor, optimize and minify the code so it will be smaller. You could even separate into multiple files per class or implementation and do a dynamic js load (but that would take more time). A good target would be as small as ext.js's.

Also if you have access to your webserver (i.e. Apache/Tomcat), you could turn on gz compression to compress files before sending to browsers. Also look out for other webserver optimizations.

(btw, your question sounds more like a webserver issue rather than a sencha related issue).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to improve the load time of your application is making sure ext.js and app-all.js are cached by the browser. This way the first time your application loads it will be slow, but the following loads will be faster.

Look into the cache-control, expires and other HTTP cache controlling headers ([this](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) appears to be a nice explanation). Your server should generate this headers when sending the files you want to be cached.

The real problem, as it appears from the timeline, is the slow connection to the server (10 seconds loading 206/665 KB is slow for most connections), so you should see if there are no other server problems causing the slowness.